# Calculating molecular weight in python

Tags: python

So I want to create a program to calculate molecular weight using just three molecules C = 12.0110, H = 1.0079, and O = 15.9994. The user will input a formula like H2O and the program should output the calculate weight of '18.01528'. 
I'm just stumped on how to create a way to multiply a letter with a number and also how to calculate it whether the formula inputted is two characters long or longer.
So far I have a dictionary:

```
elements = {
'C' : 12.0110,
'H' : 1.0079,
'O' : 15.9994
}
```

Output should look like this:

```
Enter a chemical formula, or just the enter key to quit: C2H5OH
The molecular weight is 46.0688
```

Python 3.6.1
Thanks!

Comment: Like [this challenge on CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118715/build-a-mass-spectrometer/118725#118725) you mean ?

Comment: @PaulR I think it's the opposite of what you have posted. :D

Comment: @rbaleksandar Yea it's the opposite!

Comment: Ah, well, just invert the logic then. ;-)

Comment: I've added the outlines of a solution that should work and be easy to implement. I also forgot to handle elements with multiple characters ('Ti', ' Pb' etc.) but it's fixed now.

Comment: Also, `compounds` should be named `elements` instead :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker lol right wrong wording oops! :)

Comment: @rbaleksandar Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Please take the time to read a tutorial and learn the language. Asking on SO for others to fully solve your problem will never teach you anything. If your question consists only of a virtually codeless input and expected output, you're doing it wrong. You have to reach a level where you can ask about specific issues with your existing-but-buggy code.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm still very new to programming obviously and especially to this website. I'm learning how to ask for help on programming and I seem to be a bit misleading as it wasn't my intention to have someone write my program for me. I thought I was just giving context so people know what I'm doing or working with. That's why I said "I'm just stumped on how to create a way to multiply a letter with a number and also how to calculate it whether the formula inputted is two characters long or longer" I was just trying to get some help on specifically how to multiply letters and numbers.

Comment: If my intention was to get others to fully solve my problem, I would have just posted the actual assignment question on here (Which I've seen others do). Also, my professor obviously checks online to see if I am plagiarizing so I would never use someone else's code, I was just trying to get an idea or a push in the right direction.

Comment: I suggest you turn off your computer and get out a pencil and paper. Write in words what steps you need to take to solve the problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Will do :)

Comment: "I'm just stumped on how to create a way to multiply a letter with a number" that is because multiplying a letter by a number does not mean anything. If you work some examples by hand, you should start to understand how to write this program.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Right, I'll map it out by hand and try to get like a overall idea and approach it incrementally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to parse the string (`H2O` or whatever) and check if an element is followed by a number (or numbers), another element or nothing (end of the string).

You need to also consider the case where you can have multiple numbers next to each other (`H22O`; yes, I know that such an element isn't possible but it's just an example).

All parts of the molecule will be stored inside a list with each atom (or multiple of the same) being stored separately. This will allow you to run a simple sum over the list to get the final result.

For every character do (this will be a simple loop such as `for char in user_input: ...`):

- Check if it's alphabetic character - if so, replace it with the atom weight (or whatever it's called) and store it in a list:

  ```
  f = []
  f = [1]     # let's say H has a mass of 1 :D
  f = [1, 2]  # let's say O has a mass of 2 :D
  ```

  You will have to find the element in that table you have provided. Personally I would use a dictionary for a faster and easier access. The element's alphabetic representation will be the key and it's mass will be the value. If you need to handle elements that consist of multiple characters (example: `Pb`) you can adapt the next step for handling numbers (without the last part where you convert the concatenated characters to an integer):

  ```
  e_tmp = ''
  e_tmp = e_tmp + 'P'  # P
  e_tmp = e_tmp + 'b'  # Pb

  # elements below is a dictionary. You should do an extra step to check if the key is present
  a_mass = elements.get(e_tmp)
  f.append(a_mass)
  ```
- Check if it's numeric character - store it in a temporary variable (as a string, do NOT convert it to a number!). Continue concatenating numeric character until you reach the end of the user's input OR another alphabetic character:

  ```
  tmp = ''
  tmp = tmp + '2'
  ...
  ```

  Now that you have a string with ONLY numeric characters you can convert it to an integer:

  ```
  tmpInt = int(tmp) # tmpInt = 2
  ```

  Now multiply the last cell of your list of elements that you have inserted with that number. You can keep track of the index of that cell with a variable to make the access easier:

  ```
   f = []
   f = [1]
   tmp = ''
   tmp = tmp + '2'
   tmpInt = int(tmp)
   f[last] = f[last]*tmpInt
  ```
- After you have reached the end of the string the user has entered you can sum all elements:

  ```
   molecular_weight = sum(map(int, f))
  ```

**EDIT:** [Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/elements.py.html) is a very extensive example how to store the periodic table using a dictionary though as a custom class that just uses a `dict` for internal data management.

Answer (score 3):

I'd identify two key functions:

1. Validating/parsing a formula e.g., `H2O` into a chemical symbol and the number of times it occurs. E.g., `H20` to `[('H', 2), ('O', 1)]`.

   You need to take care with chemical symbols that are a capital followed by a lower case letter, and with numbers that are more than one digit. This could be somewhat tricky, and might be broken into stages.
2. Summing the weight from the parsed formula. I.e., for `[('H', 2), ('O', 1)]` doing something like

   ```
   parsed_formula = parse(formula) # [('H', 2), ('O', 1)]
   return sum([weight[symbol] * number] for symbol, number in parsed_formula])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse the string it was fairly easy to come up with a solution that can deal with two letter elements like `Pb` and multiple digits numbers like `C10H3`. Note that this still wouldn't deal with compounds.

```
compounds = {
'C' : 12.0110,
'H' : 1.0079,
'O' : 15.9994,
'Pb': 81.4  # Added to show Aa elements working, not actual weight of Pb!
}

pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?')

z = 'Pb4O5'

total = 0.0
for element, n_str in re.findall(pattern, z):
    if n_str:
        n = int(n_str)
    else:
        # If there's no number for current element, n_str = ''
        n = 1
    total += compounds[element] * n

print(total)
```